# Compiling C++ in Matlab using mex fails

Tags: c++, macos, matlab, zlib, mex

**(NB: Details have been updated.)** I am trying to install mYm on my machine (MacBook Pro 15" running OS X 10.11.3). Having downloaded mYm, I try to compile using mex in Matlab:

`> mex -I/usr/local/mysql/include -L/usr/local/mysql/lib mym.cpp;`

However, I get the following error that I can not resolve:

```
Building with 'Xcode Clang++'.
Error using mex
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_compress", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_compressBound", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_affected_rows", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_close", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_data_seek", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_error", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_fetch_fields", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_fetch_lengths", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_fetch_row", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_field_count", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_free_result", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_get_client_info", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_get_host_info", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_get_server_info", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_init", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_num_fields", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_num_rows", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_ping", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_query", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_real_connect", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_real_escape_string", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_real_query", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_select_db", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_stat", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_mysql_store_result", referenced from:
      _mexFunction in mym.o
  "_uncompress", referenced from:
      deserialize(char const*, unsigned long) in mym.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Anyone who can help? The installation guide tells me also to include zlib include and lib files, but I do not know where they are located? I have XCode installed.

By the way:

```
>> mex -setup
MEX configured to use 'Xcode with Clang' for C language compilation.
```

Comment: There are two errors in above code: first you need static_cast<int>(length) because your compiler does not implicit conversion from long to int. second one you need to #include <cstdlib> in mym.cpp. Finally I don't think it make much sense to compile mex code in C++ mode unless you know how to use C++ objects in the mex environment, which I assume you don't, yet.

Comment: Thank you, so far. I fixed som compile errors. Please check the updated error now.

Comment: You are missing a lot of libraries. find the libraries and pass them to mex with -l and -L

Comment: Do you have any experience with mYm? It is a library that I just downloaded, I have no clue which libraries to look for. Could it be `zlib` missing?

Comment: I have no idea. You are very likely to find those functions in the headers you include, and from the headers you know what library they belong to.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a MySQL wrapper, it's very likely that you'll need to link against its libraries.

I haven't tried it, but to quote the `readme.txt` file [included](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mym/):

> the source can be compiled using the following command:
>
> ```
> mex -I[mysql_include_dir] -I[zlib_include_dir] -L[mysql_lib_dir] -L[zlib_lib_dir] -lz -lmysqlclient mym.cpp
> ```
>
> (on Mac OS X you might also need the `-lSystemStubs` switch to avoid namespace clashes)
>
> Note: to compile, the `zlib` library should be installed on the system
>   (including the headers).